# Batch file : how to get a specific part of a folder path

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently looping threw the subfolders of a known directly. I would like to grab the folder that contains the file I'm looking for, but only that folder's name, not the whole path, and preferably in a different variable to be use later on in the batch file ...

```
pause
CD c:\%username%\testFolder\Program\OLD\

For /R %%G in (test.t?t) do Echo %%G

pause
```

Now, this shows me the file I'm looking for : C:\User\testFolder\Program\OLD\myfile\exemple1\test.txt

what I would like is to replace the Echo %%G to set in a variable the "unknown" folders and subfolder, something along the line of

```
For /R %%G in (test.t?t) do set var1 = myfile\exemple1
```

anyone can point to what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `for /?` in a cmd console, you'll see runtime variables on the last couple of pages.  Using `%%~dpG` notation you can get the full drive\path specification of matched files.  Then, using substring substitution and delayed expansion, replace `%CD%` with nothing.  Finally, you can strip the leading and trailing backslash with a numeric substring -- `!varname:~1,-1!`.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "c:\%username%\testFolder\Program\OLD\"

for /R %%G in (test.t?t) do (
    set "var1=%%~dpG"
    set "var1=!var1:%CD%=!"
    if "!var1!"=="\" (echo .\) else echo(!var1:~1,-1!
)
```

If you wish, you can prevent echoing duplicates by echoing only if the previous match does not equal the current one.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "c:\%username%\testFolder\Program\OLD\"

for /R %%G in (test.t?t) do (
    set "var1=%%~dpG"
    set "var1=!var1:%CD%=!"
    if not "!var1!"=="!prev!" (
        if "!var1!"=="\" (echo .\) else echo(!var1:~1,-1!
    )
    set "prev=!var1!"
)
```

Comment: there shouldnt be any duplicate in subfolders ( unless someone messed up really really badly ) so 1st options is good enough. I'm no sure I understand the syntax of everything going on here, but it did return me the folders I needed in the 2 or 3 test I did, so case solved ! thanks alot !